# How does one mock the createClient method of the node redis module

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, mocking, sinon

I am trying to avoid a dependency on a running [redis-server](https://redis.io/) by using the [redis-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-mock) module in place of [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) module when creating a new client. Thus far I have found it impossible to mock the relevant method: `createClient`

I have gone through the [sinon documentation on stubs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.3.2/stubs/) and [an example run through](https://medium.com/@madhanganesh/how-to-mock-es6-class-749da63268fc) (found after some Googling) and based on these I have set up:

> an example app

```
// src/app.js

'use strict';

// import modules
const  express = require('express')
    , bluebird = require('bluebird')
    , redis    = require('redis')
;

// promisify redis
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);

// define constants
const app    = express()
    , client = redis.createClient()
    , port   = 3000
;

// set some values
client
  .setAsync('12345', JSON.stringify({vacancyId:12345}))
  .catch(err => console.log(`[ERROR]: error setting value - ${err}`));

// define routes
app.get('/api/vacancy/:vacancyId', (req, res) => {
  client
    .getAsync(req.params.vacancyId)
    .then(val => res.send(val))
    .catch(err => console.log(`[ERROR]: error getting value - ${err}`))
});

// listen on port
app.listen(port);

// export the app
module.exports = app;
```

> and corresponding test

```
// test/app.js

'use strict';

// import modules
const chai           = require('chai')
    , chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised')
    , chaiHttp       = require('chai-http')
    , redis          = require('redis')
    , redisMock      = require('redis-mock')
    , sinon          = require('sinon')
    , app            = require('../src/app.js')
;

// configure chai
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.use(chaiHttp);

// define constants
const expect   = chai.expect
    , response = JSON.stringify({vacancyId:12345})
;

// now test
describe.only('App', function() {
  before(function() {
    sinon
      .stub(redis.RedisClient.prototype, 'createClient')
      .callsFake(function() {
        console.log('[TEST]: i never get here :(');
        return redisMock.createClient();
      });
  });

  describe('/api/vacancy/:vacancyId', function() {
    it('should return the expected response', function() {
      return expect(chai.request(app).get('/api/vacancy/12345'))
        .to.eventually
        .have.include({status:200})
        .and
        .nested.include({text:response});
    });
  });
});
```

I would expect the test to pass (and it does when I remove the stub and point at a running redis server):

```
> scratch-node@1.0.0 test /Users/nonyiah/.src/scratch-node
> mocha --exit



  App
    /api/vacancy/:vacancyId
      ✓ should return the expected response


  1 passing (41ms)
```

but instead I get the following error:

```
> scratch-node@1.0.0 test /Users/nonyiah/.src/scratch-node
> mocha --exit



  App
    1) "before all" hook in "App"


  0 passing (10ms)
  1 failing

  1) App
       "before all" hook in "App":
     TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property createClient
      at Sandbox.stub (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/sandbox.js:308:19)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/app.js:26:8)



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

What is the correct way to achieve this mocking?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was creating the stub after the app was loaded. I need to move the instantiation of the app:

```
    // , app            = require('../src/app.js')
```

to after the stub is created:

```
  describe('/api/vacancy/:vacancyId', function() {
    it('should return the expected response', function() {
      let app = require('../src/app.js');

      return expect(chai.request(app).get('/api/vacancy/12345'))
        .to.eventually
        .have.include({status:200})
        .and
        .nested.include({text:response});
    });
  });
```